# Ajax form add more functionality in joomla module

Tags: php, joomla, module

Hi I was wondering if somebody can point me in the right direction on how to accomplish the following in a custom joomla module in the module configuration form: http://blog.cbolson.com/adding-form-fields-via-ajax-with-mootools/

So far I use a textarea to supply a list of geo data (lat, lng and label text) in the format

```
lat1,lng1|label1\r\n
lat2,lng2|label2\r\n
lat3,lng3|label3\r\n
...
```

from the module configuration. This data is displayed on a google map.

It would be nice to have a more comfortable way of adding the data like in the example on blog.cbolson.com.

Comment: In Joomla 3.2+ you also have com_ajax which will be helpful.

Comment: com_ajax isn't helpful because you need a separate module with client set to administrator in the modules xml which is pretty much useless. Otherwise the module is not assigned to admin paths and therefore is not visible and the getAjax(){...} function can not be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create fields type as array say

```
<div class="test">
<input type="text" name="data[]" />
</div>
```

and via jquery clone you can replicate that div
and since its an array you can get all entered fields this is logic you can try and 
regarding Joomla module Development you can refer Joomla DOCS

[http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aCreating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module)

Comment: Good point about the array. But how about the saving process. I might need to override something to save the data as serialized string, or?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom form field type. Visit:  http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type

Using a custom form field type, you can achieve what you want.

Comment: Yeah thanks but how to accomplish the dynamic ajax loading part.

Comment: IN function public function getInput() { }, put your js and html code. you may use same code as in blog.cbolson.com.

Comment: In 3.2+ there is also the repeatable attribute for most field types/ fieldsets. It's a little buggy but I've used it to build up json strings.

Comment: Mmmm, that repeatable fieldtype sounds exactly right for you (Thanks @Elin for making me aware of this, i've really been missing this feature). ( Unless it's so buggy it's not working, though ). The link to the documentation is here: http://docs.joomla.org/Repeatable_form_field_type

Comment: What happened the last time I used it (which I did to build a json string -- really nice) if you click cancel it kind of falls apart. But there may be something in the tracker, I know people were working on it.

Answer (score 0):

Well in that case first of all let me say that there are no from field type for button. So you have to perform the action with other event.  may be with a radio button change event.

Next is as said by Mr Rahul, you have to create your own custom form field which should have a field path (addfieldpath attribute) that you can learn from [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type).

And then add a custom.js file to your custom file that is given to the addfieldpath attribute and perform the ajax action there as per your requirement.